# 12.04 installer won't accept mis-alligned partition

Tags: installation, partitioning

So I upgraded Ubuntu from 10.04 to 12.04 and it had issues. Long story short, I backed up everything and want to reinstall.

The installer apparently REALLY doesn't like installing on mis-aligned partitions. I get the error
`The partition /dev/sda5 assigned to / starts on an offset of 3072 bytes`... There are two buttons at the bottom "Go Back" and  "Continue" the problem is that they both do the same thing - namely it kicks me back to the partition table screen.

***How do I force it to continue?***

note: Formatting the entire drive is not an option as it has a windows installation on there (sda1, 2 and 3)

Answer (score 0):

If you allow the 12.04 installer to create the partitions it will round up the starting and ending sectors so that they will fall on a megabyte boundary--even if the preceding partition doesn't end on a megabyte boundary. In fact, it only allows locations and sizes to be specified as integral number of megabytes.

I suggest that you use the installer to add the partition(s) you will be using for Ubuntu (by clicking `Other` rather than choosing to format the entire disk, of course).

As an example I manually created a first partition ending at sector 4000 and allowed the Ubuntu installer to create the root partition following it. The following was the result:

```
   Device Boot      Start       End      Blocks    ID  System
/dev/sda1           2048        4000       976+    83  Linux
/dev/sda2           4096    20969471   10482688    83  Linux
```

I was able to get the install going on /dev/sda2.

I must admit it's not clear to me what panel is displaying the message you are seeing. The partitioning panel has `Quit`, `Back`, and `Install Now` buttons at the bottom.

If you don't find this helpful please post more information about how you partitioned the disk and where you are getting the message.